# Appending to list works in MongoDB shell, but not in Node,js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the structure of the file.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f45274bbbe768fe0d56d9d0"),
        "article" : "article-name",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "id" : "_lj7cfhx7z",
                        "name" : "person",
                        "date" : "25/08/2020",
                        "text" : "asdasdsddsdsdasd",
                        "replies" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "person2",
                                        "date" : "25/08/2020",
                                        "text" : "replyyyteextttttt"
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "person3",
                                        "date" : "25/08/2020",
                                        "text" : "replyyyteextttttt"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "id" : "_wpdpj7kv6",
                        "name" : "person4",
                        "date" : "25/08/2020",
                        "text" : "aaaa",
                        "replies" : [ ]
                }
        ]
}
```

I am trying to write a function that appends to `replies` list given the id of the comment. When I do it in the MongoDB shell like this `db.comments.findOneAndUpdate({"article": "exif-parsing", "comments.id": "_t2aqbhi5a"}, {"$push": {"comments.$.replies": {"text": "new"}}});`, it works. But in Node.js it doesn't work.

```
var db = new DataBase("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

replyTo(article, id, name, comment) {
        db.connect("blog", "comments", function(collection) {
            var reply = {name: name, date: getCurrentDate(), text: comment};
            collection.findOneAndUpdate({"article": article, "comments.id": id}, {"$push": {"comments.$.replies": reply}});
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to use Mongoose ODM for writing such queries in nodejs.
Refer to the documentation : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Comment: See an example of using `findOneAndUpdate` using MongoDB NodeJS Driver at [CRUD Operations](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/crud/).